# Checking if any item in one set is in another set using a single comprehension possible?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following check in my unit test:

```py
assert any(pass1_task in (task for task in all_downstream_task_for_dl_task) for pass1_task in {'first_pass', 'first_cpp_pass'}), 'the test failed unexpectedly'
```

The unit test above fails, however, I am expecting it to pass.

`all_downstream_task_for_dl_task` is a set with 2 items:

```py
all_downstream_task_for_dl_task = {'cbbo_snowflake_copy_XAMS', 'first_cpp_pass.euronext3-equities_nl_A_3'}
```

In reality the list is much longer, but for simplicity let's say it contains the above two.

Is my list comprehension not doing what I expect it to?

I would expect the unit test to pass, since the second item in `all_downstream_task_for_dl_task` contains `first_cpp_pass`

Comment: `in (task for task in all_downstream_task_for_dl_task)` simplifies to `in all_downstream_task_for_dl_task`. You're checking for presence of string in set, not substring in string.

Comment: are they lists or sets?

Comment: They are sets. Ahh thanks for the above @matszwecja

Comment: Actually @matszwecja I think I do need to loop over `all_downstream_task_for_dl_task`, because I am trying to see if 'first_pass', 'first_cpp_pass' are in any of the items in `all_downstream_task_for_dl_task` -

Comment: The trouble is that if you notice, 'first_cpp_pass.euronext3-equities_nl_A_3' it CONTAINS `first_cpp_pass`, and is not exactly `first_cpp_pass`, which is why I think I need to loop over the set.

Comment: You do, but not in form of `(task for task in all_downstream_task_for_dl_task)`. If you've a comprehension that contains `x for x in ...` (unless you are filtering with `if`), that's a sign you can simplify it it to just the target collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally avoid comprehensions when its line overflows 79 characters, not only because of [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), but also because they lose their main goal of simplifying code. This is what you want to achieve, if I get it right:

```py
is_in_task = []
for pass1_task in {'first_pass', 'first_cpp_pass'}:
    for task in all_downstream_task_for_dl_task:
        is_in_task.append(pass1_task in task)

assert any(is_in_task), 'the test failed unexpectedly'
```

And with comprehension:

```py
assert any(pass1_task in task for task in all_downstream_task_for_dl_task for pass1_task in {'first_pass', 'first_cpp_pass'}), 'the test failed unexpectedly'
```

So mainly, you just have to remove the parentheses from the inner for loop because with parentheses, your code checks whether `pass1_task` is in the generator that is defined between the parentheses, which evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on when to use comprehension, I will write out the for loops